# Understanding the evaluation of long boolean expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

```
def main():
    x = True
    y = False
    z = False
    if not x or y: #False
        print (1)
    elif not x or not y and z: #False
        print (2)
    elif not x or y or not y and x: #True
        print (3)
    else:
        print (4)

main()
```

This is a logic question we are learning in a Python class. I dont understand how the answer is 3, that is how `not x or y or not y and x` is `True`, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you asked your instructor about this?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever confused with boolean expressions, it helps to use parentheses to make the sequence of evaluation clear. The parentheses can be placed by following [the precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and the associativity of operators. Then you can substitute and evaluate the results:

```
>>> (not x) or y
# not x ==> not False == False
# y == False
# False or False == False

>>> (not x) or ((not y) and z)
# not x == False 
# not y == True
# z == False
# True and z ==> True and False == False
# False or False == False

>>> ((not x) or y) or ((not y) and x)
# Evaluate it yourself
```

If you evaluate the last example yourself, you'll see how it leads to `False or True` which yields `True` thereby allowing the `if` statement that contains it to run.

Comment: So it would be   not x == F
# not y == T
# not x or y or true == T
# False or True == T 
    I get it :) Thank you! Just one question..for it to print 1 would it have to be if not x or y: #true?

Comment: oh wow..im sorry about the formatting. Im new to this site and i really dont know how to make the code cleaner.

Comment: That's ok @DanSieger. For it to be `1` you need to have at least one `True` value for the `or` operator. `x or y` (`x == True`) does the trick, so does `not x or not y` (`not y == True`)  and `x or not y` (both `x` and `not y` equal `True`).

Comment: ooooh I get it completely now. I just realized that the :#false was a comment. and so i was just super confused hahaha thank you so much for your help. I will definitely keep the way you organized the booleans in mind for my exam on thursday

Comment: To make this great answer even better you should explain the short-circuiting behaviour of `and` and `or`. And that they can take arbitrary operands, not just booleans.

Comment: I was really confused by the table of precedence at first because I have a Ruby background. The ruby one is written from highest to lowest. :)